# How can you track who made code updates in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been given oversight access to an azure account for our business.

I'm trying to see if there is a way to view the latest code updates and history.

Is there a way to do that in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Azure Account might not be enough for that. A Azure Website usually doesn't contain source files (there are exceptions e. g. plain html sites). They contain build artifacts / binaries that are build from the source files.

The code for your Azure Website is probably under version control. That means that your developer are using a plattform to commit the code. An example is Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), GitHub, etc...

You have to get access to the version control system used by your developers in order to view the latest code updates and history.